Python 3D Graph - how to make the plot interactive?
OSX 12.7 Python 3
I have a Python script that I have set the default Open with: Python Launcher 3.app
The file is a Plot3D-V2.py, it runs quickly but in order to update it I have to constantly rerun the script.
I have looked at a number of questions involving making the graph interactive (i.e., the window remains open while changes to spreadsheet data are made).
here is my code:
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, ion, draw, show
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d

import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("whitegrid", {'axes.grid' : False})

import  tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import Toplevel
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
print(file_path)


df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
print(df.head)
print(df.columns)

root.iconify()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,9))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

ax.set_xlim(0.2, 0.4)

ax.set_ylim(0.6, 0.2)

ax.set_zlim(0.2, 0.4)

for i in range(len(df)):
    ax.scatter3D(df['R'][i], df['G'][i], df['B'][i], 
                 marker=df['M'][i], c=df['C'][i], alpha=1.0)

ax.set_xlabel('Red')
ax.set_ylabel('Green')
ax.set_zlabel('Blue')

draw()

plt.show(block=False)

plt.pause(1)

plt.show(block=True)

plt.show()

Is there a simple way to embed a 'rerun script' button into the plot window?
